# Can I paste to the active window using Electron or NW.js?

Tags: javascript, macos, clipboard, electron

I'm looking for a way for my application, call it "application A", to paste the clipboard to the active window which is not controlled by me, for example, Google Chrome.  Examples of applications that do this include password managers which paste a password into the password field in another application, and clipboard managers which allow pasting of arbitrary text.

I know that I can *access* the clipboard, setting and retrieving its contents, but I want to actually take what's on the clipboard and paste it into another application.

Currently, the only way I can think to do this is to simulate a CTRL/CMD+V press, but that seems hacky.

Any advice? I'm on OS X.

Comment: what platform? windows, mac, linux?

Comment: Oh sorry! Mac! Edited.